# Login using PHP and mysqli

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

so I was trying to do a login with php and mysqli and this is how its going at the moment:

```
$DBServer = 'X'; // ip o lo que sea
$DBUser   = 'X';
$DBPass   = 'X';
$DBName   = 'X';
$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

if ($_POST['login']) {
    $usuario = (isset($_POST['usuario'])) ? $_POST['usuario'] : '';
    $pass = (isset($_POST['pass'])) ? $_POST['pass'] : '';
if ($usuario == "" or $pass == "") {
    echo 'Rellena todos los campos';
} else {
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt=$conn->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$usuario,$pass);

    $stmt->execute(); 

    $stmt->bind_result($nombre_db,$pass_db);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($nombre_db != $usuario) {
            echo'No existe el usuario';
        } else { 
        if ($pass_db !== $pass) { 
            echo'Contraseña incorrecta';
        } else { //pass correcto
        session_start();
            $_SESSION["nombre"]=$usuario;
            echo'<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0";URL="home.php">';
    }
    }
}
```

However, when I try log in nothing happens. Any idea what am I doing wrong?
The table users has two columns: user and password.Futhermore, where should this code go?

```
$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();
```

Thanks!
EDIT: The errors displayed when running this code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

are the following

> Notice: Undefined index: login in /home/u949068087/public_html/web/admin/login.php on line 39

Line 39 is the following:
    if($_POST['login']){
The actual form is the following:

```
<form method="post">
  <p>Usuario:
 <input type="text" name="usuario"  />
  </p>
  <p>
    Contraseña:
    <input type="password" name="pass"  />
    </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="login" name="login"  />
  </p>
</form>
```

What I pass through it is the following:

> Array ( [usuario] => exampleuser [pass] => examplepassword [login] => login )
>   EDIT 2:
>   As far as I am concerned, the error is in this part of the code which is not execu

```
while($stmt->fetch()){}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There is one bracket missing in the end of your code, but I suppose you missed it when you copied your code here. Make sure if it is OK.

Second thing. Do you show PHP errors? You can put this code in the beggining of your PHP file.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: What you're passing in $_POST['login']? You're code works on my Server just fine. Maybe you don't pass something correctly. You can debug this simply printing your $_POST array: print_r($_POST);exit();

Comment: Thanks! Please refer to the main post, I edited adding some extra information

Answer (score -1):

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0";URL="home.php">`

Your refresh meta has the content value set to 0 i.e the page will refresh immediately. I assume that you are coming from the home.php file to start with, meaning that you won't even notice the refresh.

Try setting the content value to something more user friendly, say 3 (seconds)

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="3";URL="home.php">`

As for `$stmt->close();` and `$mysqli->close();`, put them immediately after your while loop:

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
    if($nombre_db != $usuario){echo'No existe el usuario';}else{ //user existe
    if($pass_db != $pass){echo'Contraseña incorrecta';}else{ //pass correcto
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that even if I type a username which does not exist or a wrong password, I do not get the error messages

Comment: What Dolchio is suggesting is that your page is in a constant refresh state, and the content never gets to be displayed.

Comment: I've changed it 3 as you suggested and I still get nothing, whether i type the user and password correctly, one of them wrong, or both of them wrong...